# Gradient estimates of linear elliptic PDE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded smooth domain. Assume that $u(x)$ is the classical solution solving
$$a_{ij}(x)\partial_{ij}u(x)+b_i(x)\partial_iu(x)+c(x)u(x)=f(x)$$
$$u(x)\Big|_{\partial \Omega}=g(x)$$
for some smooth enough coefficients and uniformly elliptic $a_{ij}$. I found that in Gilbarg and Trudinger's PDE book, Theorem 8.33 states that
$$ |u|_{1,\alpha,\Omega'}\leq C(|u|_{0}+|g|_{0}+|f|_{0,\alpha}) $$
for $\Omega' \subset \Omega$ and some constant $C$ depending on the $C^{0,\alpha}$-norms of $a_{ij}$, $b_i$ and $c$ (and some other parameters).

Now, I am looking for a upper bound of $|\nabla u|$ on $\Omega'$, not the holder norm, can this upper be something like
$$ \sup_{\Omega'}|u|\leq C(|u|_{0}+|g|_{0}+|f|_{0}) $$
for some constant $C$ depending on the $C^{0}$-norms of $a_{ij}$, $b_i$ and $c$, but not their holder norms? If this is to complicated, we can deal with the ODE case or equation in divergence form.

Comment: Your answer can be found also in Gilbarg and Trudinger's book in section 8.11.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Theorem 8.33 I mentioned in the above is found in section 8.1 of GT's book. But the constant $C$ in there depends on the Holder norm of the coefficients as the Holder norm of the gradient is controlled in there. I just want to control the sup norm of gradient, not the Holder norm, can the constant $C$ depend on the sup norm of the coefficient, not the Holder norm in this case?

Comment: Oups, sorry, I read too quickly your question... these equations are not in divergence form so I do not know the answer.

Comment: We can consider the divergence form first, let's say $\nabla\cdot (a\nabla u)=f(x)$